# Saving changes to objects in gazebo_ros world file?

Tags: ros, world, gazebo-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working in ROS (Indigo, Ubuntu 14), starting gazebo 2.2.3 with

```
rosrun gazebo_ros gazebo
```

I go in and create a little corner of a room by dropping in a couple of cubes and scaling them:

[image description http://answers.gazebosim.org/upfiles/14717013818196838.png](http://answers.gazebosim.org/upfiles/14717013818196838.png)

I save the file as corner.world. Then later open it, and the scaling I did is gone:

[image description http://answers.gazebosim.org/upfiles/14717014275085737.png](http://answers.gazebosim.org/upfiles/14717014275085737.png)

I've now just got two cubes. Where did my walls go?

Note: cross-posted at:
http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14206/world-changes-not-saved-after-editing-in-gazebo_ros-223/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242109/saving-changes-to-objects-in-gazebo_ros-world-file?/) by [neuronet](https://answers.ros.org/users/27484/neuronet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2016-08-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From [gazebo answers:](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14206/world-changes-not-saved-after-editing-in-gazebo_ros-223/?answer=14208#post-id-14208)

> There were a few issues scaling shapes
> and saving the world which have been
> fixed in newer versions of Gazebo.
> Since Gazebo 2 is no longer officially
> supported, I suggest you change to the
> latest long term support version,
> Gazebo 7.

Unfortunately, Gazebo 2.N is what comes packaged with Indigo. It is indeed possible to go renegade and install more recent versions of Gazebo:
http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_wrapper_versions
Those intrepid souls who want to follow those instructions, live it up!

One workaround is to build walls out of cubes.

---

Originally posted by [neuronet](https://answers.ros.org/users/27484/neuronet/) with karma: 39 on 2016-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [neuronet](https://answers.ros.org/users/27484/neuronet/) on 2016-08-21**:
Why is the default to install an unsupported version of gazebo with an actively supported version of ROS? Gazebo is up to version 7 now! #roswtf